# VMWare vs. Windows Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

Any reason not to use Windows' built in vm stuff over VMWare?
I want to run 64-bit RedHat as the guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lots of reasons. The question is:

- Are they valid for you and
- Are they worth the ridiculous high VmWare price for you? (because mostly the really nice features are in the highly paid version)

VmWare has more features (dynamic memory, real time backup of a running VM to another running one, so if one host crashes, the other takes over immediately), but they all are in the really high cost version - and in absolutely most cases make little sense (as in: nice to have, but in no way something I want to pay for).

Take that out, and you are left with eiher:

- A harder to maintain hyper-visor. Vmware is monolithic, windows "open" - for drivers. The supported hardware is a lot smaller for VmWare thanks to special drivers needed.
- A similar effective feature set.

Take hat you want. As a Unix dude you will possibly prefer vmware, as a windows person I prefer hyper-v... also because I know the administrative side better, including scripting.

Comment: In my experience with the VMWare hypervisor it seems much more intuitive and easy to use. I don't really understand how you can say the amount of supported platforms is less, given that VMWare supports nearly every major OS in multiple version whereas Hyper-V supports almost nothing but the Windows OS (meaning with full Virtual tools, etc.)

Comment: I meant PLATFORM - not "supported client". Hyper-V you can install basically everywhere you can install windows - every hardware manufacturer has drivers for windows. VMWare has SERIOUS problems limitations on the hardware side. Finding you like VmWare better, but no, it does not install on your laptop / your whatever motherboard is not exactly "wide platform support".

Comment: For more intuitive to use - you obviously are not a windows guy. Windows people will be used to PowerShell and like the fact that no, they do nt have to learn another OS just to run a hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Generically:

1. Use what your familiar with.
2. If #1 doesn't apply, each have different licensing costs. Find the cheaper for your situation.

If you have Windows on the server already, and just want to run one guest VM, I'd just pop Hyper-V on the machine. It'll be quick, simple, and easy.